# Can't filter NaN values while using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This code:

```
import re
class_size=data["class_size"]
def is_912(string):
    if pd.isnull(string)==True:
        return False
    if re.search('09-12',string) is not None:
          return True
    else:
          return False

is_9or12=class_size['GRADE '].apply(is_912)
class_size['GRADE ']=class_size['GRADE '][is_9or12==True]
print(class_size['GRADE '])
```

Gives the following result:

```
0          NaN
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
4          NaN
5          NaN
6          NaN
...
27605    09-12
27606    09-12
27607    09-12
27608    09-12
27609    09-12
```

I can't understand why my function isn't filtering out the NaN values?

Comment: What is your original data frame like? Chances are you're going about this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using `apply()`.  It defeats the purpose of Pandas, which is efficient vectorized computation.  It reintroduces Python looping and slow execution, and 98% of the time it is used without necessity.

Try something like this:

```
class_size = data["class_size"]
is_9or12 = class_size['GRADE '].isin(('09', '10', '11', '12'))
```

It isn't really clear from your question what your data look like, but here are some string-specific methods that work in Pandas and are fast:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

Comment: Sound advice, but I'm not sure this is what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: That's OK, I don't think OP knows either.  Maybe with this idea in hand they can move forward.

Comment: Thank you, but can you plz tell me why what I wrote isnt working ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop the nans you can use the dropna method, look this example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=np.arange(5), columns=['A'])

without_nan = df.dropna(subset = ['A'])
```

In some cases it will be better to use :

```
df[np.isfinite(df['A'])]
```

Comment: I know, but Im intrested in why what i wrote isnt working.

Comment: The question is not clear but if you want more help we need to know the structure of the data variable

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're only replacing the values of the column `GRADE` where the corresponding value in your `class_size` vector is `True`. As it sounds like you may not fundamentally understand what you've built, I'll try to explain why:

```
is_9or12=class_size['GRADE '].apply(is_912)
```

This line of code is creating a new vector (array) of `True` or `False` values, of the same length as the `GRADE` column of the DataFrame. Since we can't see your data set, I'll assume for now the logic in the `is_912` function works as you expect.

```
class_size['GRADE ']=class_size['GRADE '][is_9or12==True]
```

This line of code will replace the values in the `GRADE` column with itself (?) for indexes where the `is_9or12` vector has a `True` value.

Since you aren't doing anything to change or remove the `NaN` values in the column, they remain exactly where they were before you executed these lines of code.

Again, without a reproducible example, this is only speculation, but I think it's what you're asking for.